# La clase de destino no existe. Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Al tratar de obtener registros de una tabla obtengo este error:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Usuarios\UsuariosController] does not exist.

web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthControllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Usuarios;

Route::get('ver-usuarios', [App\Http\Controllers\Usuarios\UsuariosController::class, 'index'])->name('ver-usuarios');
```

Controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Usuarios;
namespace App\Models;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;




class UsuariosController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $usuarios_activos = User::where('estado','ACTIVO')->get();
        dd($usuarios_activos);
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error parece iniciar de que a tu clase controladora *UsuariosController* la estás declarando bajo el *contexto* de 2 namespaces.

Entonces *`App\Models`* esta anulando a *`App\Http\Controllers\Usuarios`* y por eso al momento que intentas usar la clase en otro lado esta misma no puede ser localizada.

Lo anterior te lo ejemplifico de esta manera:

```
<?php

namespace Stack;
namespace Trace;

class Clase
{
    
}

var_dump(Clase::class);
```

Cuya salida será:

> string(11) "Trace\Clase"

Comentarios finales:

- Como puedes observar *Clase* queda bajo el segundo *namespace*
- Entonces si eliminas a *`namespace App\Models`* de tu controlador debería andar tu código.
- Por otro lado puedes evitar escribir 2 veces lo mismo si invocas a *`UsuariosController`* ya sea al inicio con *`use`* **o bien** cuando empleas a dicha clase en la ruta *`get`*
- [Puedes checar la doc. de PHP al respecto de *namespaces*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.php)